# How to define a signature of an argument receiving the runOnUiThread Java method?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass the `runOnUiThread` method to my `ServerThread`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var serverThread: Thread

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // stuff...
        this.serverThread = Thread(ServerThread(runOnUiThread))
        this.serverThread.start()
    }
}

class ServerThread(val runOnUiThread: (() -> Unit) -> Unit) : Runnable{
    override fun run() {
        // stuff...
    }
}
```

But getting compliation error for `this.serverThread = Thread(ServerThread(runOnUiThread))`:

[image]

I understand that it is a Java object (neither `@Nullable` nor `@NotNull`). I tried, among many other things: `(() -> Unit)!` and `Runnable!` in signature with no success. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `runOnUiThread` in functional syntax is `(Runnable) -> Unit`. And you pass it as an argument using `::`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var serverThread: Thread

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // stuff...
        this.serverThread = Thread(ServerThread(::runOnUiThread))
        this.serverThread.start()
    }
}

class ServerThread(runOnUiThread: (Runnable) -> Unit) : Runnable{
    override fun run() {
        // stuff...
    }
}
```